# custom image in shopping cart

Tags: magento2.3, module, custom, shopping-cart

I would like to customize the shopping cart by adding pictures right between the headline "Shopping Cart" and below the Item table but haven't figured out yet where the xml files are to overwrite this behaviour. Does anyone know where i can change that behaviour?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override checkout_cart_index.xml

```
vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\layout\checkout_cart_index.xml
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, exactly what I'm looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

File is **checkout_cart_index.xml**

You Can place your custom image after **page.main.title**